# Why does my script that contains "from file import class" fail to run?

Tags: python-3.x, class, python-import

I am trying to run an example of OOP I copied from *"Learning Python (5th edition)"* by Mark Lutz. It's the first example from *Chapter 31* which I'll reproduce ahead for your convenience.

I wrote the following script in a file called *employees.py*, which sets up a class structure that simulates a pizza shop team:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary=0):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
    def giveRaise(self, percent):
        self.salary = self.salary + (self.salary * percent)
    def work(self):
        print(self.name, "does stuff")
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<Employee: name=%s, salary=%s>" % (self.name, self.salary)

class Chef(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, 50000)
    def work(self):
        print(self.name, "makes food")

class Server(Employee):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Employee.__init__(self, name, 40000)
    def work(self):
    print(self.name, "interfaces with customer")

class PizzaRobot(Chef):
    def __init__(self, name):
        Chef.__init__(self, name)
    def work(self):
        print(self.name, "makes pizza")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    bob = PizzaRobot('bob')
    print(bob)
    bob.work()
    bob.giveRaise(0.20)
    print(bob); print()

    for klass in Employee, Chef, Server, PizzaRobot:
        obj = klass(klass.__name__)
        obj.work()
```

It works as expected when I run the script from the command prompt.

Then I wrote the following script, *pizzashop.py*, which simulates customers' orders from that pizza shop.

```
from employees import PizzaRobot, Server

class Customer:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
    def order(self, server):
        print(self.name, "orders from", server)
    def pay(self, server):
        print(self.name, "pays for item to", server)

class Oven:
    def bake(self):
        print("oven bakes")

class PizzaShop:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = Server('Pat')
        self.chef   = PizzaRobot('Bob')
        self.oven   = Oven()

def order(self, name):
    customer = Customer(name)
    customer.order(self.server)
    self.chef.work()
    self.oven.bake()
    customer.pay(self.server)

if __name__ == "___main__":
    scene = PizzaShop()
    scene.order('Homer')
    print('...')
    scene.order('Shaggy')
```

However, nothing happens when I run this last script from the command prompt. I get blank then the prompt again.

I am running Python 3.8 on a Windows 10. I think I had this problem before when the file name and the class name clashed but that doesn't seem to be the issue here. Can somebody please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your indentation as you see it, because you have a couple of indentation problems, but you would receive explicit errors if that is the case. Your `"___main__"` issue is that the you have 3 `___`s at the beginning, it needs to be just 2 (dunder - double under), e.g. `"__main__"`.

Comment: @AChampion Thanks mate, that was it, the issue with "__main__". Please make it an answer so I can mark this question as resolved by you. Thanks once again :^)